# Using Apostrophe ' ' in custom format for date

Tags: c#, datetime

In docs for Microsoft C# says

> To change the time separator for a particular date and time string, specify the separator character within a literal string delimiter.
>   For example, the custom format string `hh'_'dd'_'ss` produces a result string in which "_" (an underscore) is always used as the time separator.

In my code i tried to use separator for Date with both ways with and without Apostrophe as shown
but the Result were the same for both outputs !

**With Apostrophe**

```
var __Date = new DateTime(1998, 07, 8, 07, 5, 1).ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd hh':'mm':'ss");
```

the output as : 1998-07-08 07:05:01

**Without Apostrophe**

```
var _Date = new DateTime(1998,07,8,07,5,1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

the output as : 1998-07-08 07:05:01

Could some one really tell me what is the purpose for Apostrophe in the separator for date in docs ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The `:` custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the--custom-format-specifier) has special meaning as:

> *replace me with the current culture or supplied culture time separator*.

That means, if you use a culture that *doesn't* have `:` as a [`TimeSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.timeseparator), that `:` replaced with your current culture's `TimeSeparator` in the output. Those apostrophes are there to escape your time separator *no matter* your current culture time separator is `:` or not.

Your first code generates `:` as an output *no matter what* your current culture's `TimeSeparator` since you escape them.

Your second code generates `:` as an output *only* if your current culture has `:` as a `TimeSeparator`.

For example, `ml-IN` culture does have `.` as a `TimeSeparator` (at least in .net framework 4.6.1 and be aware, those separators *might* change over .net framework or os version). If you change your `CurrentCulture` to `ml-IN`, you will get `1998-07-08 07.05.01` as an output.

These rules are the same for [the `/` custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the--custom-format-specifier-1) as well as a [`DateSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator).

Comment: Nice info, was not aware of the exact purpose till now.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the section before that in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the--custom-format-specifier):

> The ":" custom format specifier represents the time separator, which is used to differentiate hours, minutes, and seconds. **The appropriate localized time separator is retrieved from the DateTimeFormatInfo.TimeSeparator property of the current or specified culture.**

What this means is, if you use the default time separator `:`, it will be replaced based on the default or specified [culture settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Globalization_CultureInfo_InvariantCulture) (for language localization).